# Strange magic __get() behavior in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I was studying magic PHP's methods and came up with very strange behavior. My code:

```
<?php
class Magic
{
    public $a = "A";
    protected $b = ["a" => "A", "b" => "B", "c" => "C"];
    protected $c = [1, 2, 3];

    public function __get($v)
    {
        echo "$v,";
        return $this->b[$v];
    }
}

$m = new Magic();

echo $m->a.",";
echo $m->b.",";
echo $m->c;

echo PHP_EOL;

echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c;
```

Output:

```
A,b,B,c,C
b,c,A,B,C
```

I was hoping to get something like this:

```
A,b,B,,c,,C
A,b,B,,c,,C
```

Why output lines are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've edited the magic method like this, added internal to the output.

```
public function __get($v)
{
    echo " internal $v,";
    return $this->b[$v];
}
```

And i got

```
A, internal b,B, internal c,C
internal b, internal c,A,B,C
```

So, when we call `$m->a` it returns the `a` property because it's defined `public`ly.

$b and $c are protected, which means our magic method is going to work.

`echo $m->a.",";` Says `A,`, without invoking the magic __get method. Because a is a public property.

While `echo $m->b.",";` says `internal b, B,` because it invokes our magic method.

We gave the variables one by one, but in the second call, we want all three at once.

In this case, when we give all three variables to `echo` command at once; it first tries and gets all three of them, and then print them on the screen. (see [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/jon)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613677/strange-magic-get-behavior-in-php#comment32658104_21613916).)

While the echo command is collecting its information, it invokes our magic *__get* method twice for b and c and **our method** prints something on the screen. (`internal b, internal c,`) Then, after our magic methods returned and echo command collected the info it needed, it prints what it's got, which is `A,B,C`

Comment: *"it'll first try and get all three of them, and then will print them on the screen"* => Yes, in the sense that this is obviously what happens here. But no, in the sense that you can't count on it. It just *happens* to be this way today, for this particular piece of code.

Comment: @Jon yeah, you're right, that wasn't what i meant though. I have edited the answer, thanks for warning.

Answer (score 2):

When you do: `echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c;`, you get `b,c,A,B,C`, because the echo statements by `__get` (in lowercase) are executed before the `$m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c` string is concatenated and therefore before any of it (`A,B,C`) is echoed.

In the other case, you echo after each __get call, so the output (`A,b,B,c,C`) has the values intermingled.

Answer (score 2):

That is actually expected behavior.

When accessing virtual property like `b` or `c` your code first echos its name and then returns its value which is then echoed.

```
echo $m->b.',';
```

is same as

```
echo "b,"; // echo "$v," from __get(b)
echo "B" . ","; // echo return value from __get(b)
```

Same happens after echoing PHP_EOL. It first processes all echo's "arguments" and thus echoing all variable names, then returning values, concatenating and echoing them.

```
echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c;
```

is same as

```
echo "b,"; // echo "$v," from __get(b)
echo "c,"; // echo "$v," from __get(c)
echo "A" . ","; // echo value of public property a
echo "B" . ","; // echo return value from __get(b)
echo "C"; // echo return value from __get(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line of output should not be surprising:

```
echo $m->a.",";  // $m->a is accessible, prints "A,"
echo $m->b.",";  // not accessible, __get called, prints "b,", ret, prints "B,"
echo $m->c;      // not accessible, __get called, prints "c,", ret, prints "C"
```

The final result should be `A,b,B,c,C` as you observed.

The second line is surprising at first sight, but not that much if you think about it. It has to do with the order of evaluation of the sub-expressions in `$m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c`.

As is evident from the result, what PHP does is first evaluate all three property reads in order of appearance (which immediately causes the side effects `b,` and `c,` to appear) and only then concatenates the results. This produces `A,B,C`, which is appended.

PHP **does not guarantee any particular order of evaluation** for sub-expressions, either in this or in any other situation. This means that you have to be very careful if you have expressions that cause side effects, as these side effects may be observed to happen in a counter-intuitive order (you have already found out).

Exploratory exercises aside, a good rule of thumb to follow in PHP (and also in any other imperative language) is to **not write code that produces a result together with side effects** (which is really a special case of the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

Comment: Are you saying that when using concatenation the evaluation order of the expressions is not predictable? That doesn't sound right

Comment: @onetrickpony: Perhaps, if you are coming from certain other languages. However it's the simple truth. I invite you to find any piece of PHP documentation that says otherwise. I hope we can agree that in the absence of explicit guarantees, no guarantees exist.

Comment: "these side effects may be observed to happen in a counter-intuitive order (you have already found out)" -- But they do happen in an intuitive order: `b` is output before `c`

Comment: @onetrickpony: Or you might prefer to take [the word of a core developer](https://gist.github.com/nikic/6699370) over mine.

Comment: @Boann: Perhaps the wording can be improved (suggestions?), but I think you get the gist -- side effects can appear at any point. Even `b,c` is not guaranteed.